# Sensitivity and specificity

Tags: sas

I need to calculate the following for my dataset. I could calculate individual PPV (95% CI) and NPV (95% CI) but got tad confused about how to calculate this:

PPV+NPV-1 (95% CI)

How do I do this calculation?

Answer (score 1):

[This page on SAS support](http://support.sas.com/kb/24/170.html) gives code as follows:

```
title 'Sensitivity';
      proc freq data=FatComp;
         where Response=1;
         weight Count;
         tables Test / binomial(level="1");
         exact binomial;
         run;

      title 'Specificity';
      proc freq data=FatComp;
         where Response=0;
         weight Count;
         tables Test / binomial(level="0");
         exact binomial;
         run;

      title 'Positive predictive value';
      proc freq data=FatComp;
         where Test=1;
         weight Count;
         tables Response / binomial(level="1");
         exact binomial;
         run;

      title 'Negative predictive value';
      proc freq data=FatComp;
         where Test=0;
         weight Count;
         tables Response / binomial(level="0");
         exact binomial;
         run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this is a useful measure. In general you should present sensitivity, specificity, positive and negative predictive values. If you want a global measure of accuracy you should go for the proportion of correctly classified subjects.

If you go in the [webpage](https://support.sas.com/kb/24/170.html) already suggested by Peter Flom yo can scroll until a piece of code for overall accuracy. The accuracy can be computed by creating a binary variable  indicating whether test and response agree in each observation. :

```
data acc; 
     set FatComp;
     if (test and response) or 
        (not test and not response) then acc=1; 
     else acc=0;
     run;
  proc freq;
     weight count;
     tables acc / binomial(level="1");
     exact binomial;
     run;
```

Hope it helps